# Время появление элемента CSS (свойство transition)

Tags: css, css3, css-animation

К определенному элементу установлено свойство transition для плавного появления при наведении. Но он также плавно исчезает, если увести мышку с элемента. Возможно ли сделать исчезновение элемента без использования анимации (чтобы если отвел фокус от элемента, он исчезал сразу, а если навел - то появлялся медленно)?

Вопрос конечно в рамках CSS хотелось бы решить.

PS вопрос в реализации меню...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Стоит всего лишь задать `transition` для `:hover` эффекта

*Если удобнее, то можете посмотреть реализацию Вашей задачи на codepen: [ссылка](https://codepen.io/meine89/pen/aPjEGZ)*

```css
.content {
  border: 5px solid red;
  max-width: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.test {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: pink;
  opacity: 0;
}

.test:hover {
  transition: opacity 1s;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="test"></div>
</div>
```